# Retrospect API available?

Tags: retrospect

Is there an API or programmatic calling system for Roxio Retrospect?

Because of the naming conventions within the system, trying to search for "scripting" or anything of the like refers to the context of creating backup scripts through the GUI, not programatic scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on past research, sadly Retrospect does not support a Programmatic API for external scripting.

Comment: Bugger. Cheers for the answer.